# Pandas error when using resample and groupby to apply function

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python. I used to code in R and work with `period_apply` function. So I tried the following approaches in python below.

First, I do not understand what the errors are trying to tell me.
Second, I do not understand why I only get errors with `groupby` if I include the first row of the data. Yet with `resample`, i get error no matter whether I include the first row or not. 
Third, how do I resolve this problem, please do not tell me skip the first row, **because I work with a much much bigger dataset**

**Data**

```
                           Best_Bid  Best_Ask
Timestamp                                  
2019-05-02 11:59:59.602   29636.0   29638.0
2019-05-02 12:59:00.033       NaN       NaN
2019-05-02 12:59:00.033       NaN       NaN
2019-05-02 12:59:00.033       NaN       NaN
2019-05-02 12:59:00.033       NaN       NaN
2019-05-02 12:59:00.033       NaN       NaN
2019-05-02 12:59:00.033       NaN       NaN

{'Best_Bid': {Timestamp('2019-05-02 11:59:59.602000'): 29636.0,
  Timestamp('2019-05-02 12:59:00.033000'): nan},
 'Best_Bid_Q': {Timestamp('2019-05-02 11:59:59.602000'): 4.0,
  Timestamp('2019-05-02 12:59:00.033000'): nan},
 'Best_Ask': {Timestamp('2019-05-02 11:59:59.602000'): 29638.0,
  Timestamp('2019-05-02 12:59:00.033000'): nan}}
```

And I am trying to apply the below function(I know I could have just done `.agg({'Best_Bid':['last']})` but this is a simplified version of my original code).

**Function**

```
def func(x):
    best_bid = (x['Best_Bid'])[-1]
    best_ask = (x['Best_Ask'])[-1]
    return pd.Series([best_bid,best_ask], index=['bbbid', 'aaask'])
```

**groupby and grouper**
If I skip the first row and run. Things work fine.

```
df.iloc[1:,:].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='180S',closed='right',label='right',base=-0.0001)).apply(func)


                               bbbid  aaask
Timestamp                                  
2019-05-02 12:59:59.999899904    NaN    NaN
```

However, if i include the first row, I got the following error.

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='180S',closed='right',label='right',base=-0.0001)).apply(func)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4405, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 90, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 471, in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 997, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1004, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: -1
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-191-85550b07b869>", line 1, in <module>
    df.iloc[371448:371455,0:3].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='180S',closed='right',label='right',base=-0.0001)).apply(func)
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 735, in apply
    result = self._python_apply_general(f)
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 751, in _python_apply_general
    keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, self._selected_obj, self.axis)
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py", line 206, in apply
    res = f(group)
  File "<ipython-input-104-c57c7e2b6885>", line 2, in func
    best_bid = (x['Best_Bid'])[-1]
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 871, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py", line 651, in get_value
    value = Index.get_value(self, series, key)
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4411, in get_value
    return libindex.get_value_at(s, key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 44, in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 45, in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at
  File "pandas\_libs\util.pxd", line 98, in pandas._libs.util.get_value_at
  File "pandas\_libs\util.pxd", line 89, in pandas._libs.util.validate_indexer
IndexError: index out of bounds
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4405, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 90, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 471, in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 997, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1004, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: -1
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-191-85550b07b869>", line 1, in <module>
    df.iloc[371448:371455,0:3].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='180S',closed='right',label='right',base=-0.0001)).apply(func)
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 735, in apply
    result = self._python_apply_general(f)
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 751, in _python_apply_general
    keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, self._selected_obj, self.axis)
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\ops.py", line 206, in apply
    res = f(group)
  File "<ipython-input-104-c57c7e2b6885>", line 2, in func
    best_bid = (x['Best_Bid'])[-1]
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 871, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py", line 651, in get_value
    value = Index.get_value(self, series, key)
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4411, in get_value
    return libindex.get_value_at(s, key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 44, in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 45, in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at
  File "pandas\_libs\util.pxd", line 98, in pandas._libs.util.get_value_at
  File "pandas\_libs\util.pxd", line 89, in pandas._libs.util.validate_indexer
IndexError: index out of bounds
```

**Resample**

I got the following error regardless of including the first row or not.

```
df.resample(rule='180S',closed='right',label='right',base=-0.0001).agg(func)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4411, in get_value
    return libindex.get_value_at(s, key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 44, in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 45, in pandas._libs.index.get_value_at
  File "pandas\_libs\util.pxd", line 98, in pandas._libs.util.get_value_at
  File "pandas\_libs\util.pxd", line 83, in pandas._libs.util.validate_indexer
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py", line 651, in get_value
    value = Index.get_value(self, series, key)
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4419, in get_value
    raise e1
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4405, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 90, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 473, in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 479, in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine._date_check_type
KeyError: 'Best_Bid'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 520, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.convert_str_to_tsobject
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\parsing.pyx", line 228, in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_datetime_string
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 1374, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 649, in parse
    raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: Best_Bid
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py", line 660, in get_value
    return self.get_value_maybe_box(series, key)
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py", line 675, in get_value_maybe_box
    key = Timestamp(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\timestamps.pyx", line 418, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp.__new__
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 292, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.convert_to_tsobject
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 523, in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.convert_str_to_tsobject
ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-190-d2caa0c5152a>", line 1, in <module>
    df.iloc[371448:371455,0:3].resample(rule='180S',closed='right',label='right',base=-0.0001).agg(func)
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 285, in aggregate
    result = self._groupby_and_aggregate(how, grouper, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 359, in _groupby_and_aggregate
    result = grouped._aggregate_item_by_item(how, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 1172, in _aggregate_item_by_item
    result[item] = colg.aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 269, in aggregate
    result = self._aggregate_named(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 452, in _aggregate_named
    output = func(group, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-104-c57c7e2b6885>", line 2, in func
    best_bid = (x['Best_Bid'])[-1]
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 871, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\Users\testUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py", line 662, in get_value
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'Best_Bid'
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you are getting an error with the `(x['Best_Bid'])[-1]` because it is returning a KeyError: -1

Your apply function is iterating though each element (x) from the column (Best_Bid and Bid_Ask) and trying to grab the last index from the element (x) which doesn't make sense.

I don't have your dataset in front of me to work with but I would try this code to see if it works.

```
gdf = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='180S',closed='right',label='right',base=-0.0001)).copy()

print(gdf['Best_Bid'][gdf.index[-1]],gdf.index[-1])
print(gdf['Best_Ask'][gdf.index[-1]],gdf.index[-1])
```

Now this code can definitely be simplified but it should work for all rows and it will be much faster than the .apply method if it is a large dataset.

Comment: I am stilling getting the same error after editing the code to `x['Best_Bid'][x.index[-1]]`

Comment: Are you using this function to grab the last element from the column?

Comment: I edited my answer. Go check it out and see if that works for you.